# Yii2 PHP Framework pegar valor RadioList

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

Bom gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o valor selecionado na RadioList do Yii2 Framework:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'RADIO_LIST')->radioList($values, array('class' => 'test-checks'));  ?>
        </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das opções passadas no array $values será selecionada pelo usuário, e será possível manipular esse valor no Controller desta view, por exemplo:

**create.php**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'RADIO_LIST')->radioList($values, array('class' => 'test-checks'));  ?>
        </div>  
</div> 

<button class="btn-primary btn" type="submit">Salvar</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Então no Controller você pegará da requisição os dados passados no formulário:

**DefaultController.php**

```
public function ActionCreate()
{
    $model = new Usuario();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post); // insere o atributo (popula) no $model;

    $model->save();

    return $this->render('view', compact('model'));
}
```

**view.php**

```
<?= $model->RADIO_LIST ?> // exibe na tela o seu atributo com o valor passado no *create.php*
```

**RESUMO**

No formulário da tela *create.php* foi criado o campo do formulário do tipo radio list, com um array de opções para o usuário selecionar (variavel *$values*), ao clicar em submit, esse valor selecionado seria vinculado ao campo, e seria enviado para o controller onde seria feito todo o tratamento (validações, persistência, etc..), no fim do controller é chamado a tela *view.php*, onde enfim o valor é acessado e exibido na tela.